# Encountering an error when using " tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm looking to implement reproducibility for Keras models and have been testing with sample code found online in TensorFlow environments 2.9 and 2.10. However, I'm encountering the same error in both environments, and I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.

https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/reproducibility_recipes/

```
"""
Title: Reproducibility in Keras Models
Author: [Frightera](https://github.com/Frightera)
Date created: 2023/05/05
Last modified: 2023/05/05
Description: Demonstration of random weight initialization and reproducibility in Keras models.
Accelerator: GPU
"""
"""
## Introduction
This example demonstrates how to control randomness in Keras models. Sometimes
you may want to reproduce the exact same results across runs, for experimentation
purposes or to debug a problem.
"""

"""
## Setup
"""
import json

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

# Set the seed using keras.utils.set_random_seed. This will set:
# 1) `numpy` seed
# 2) `tensorflow` random seed
# 3) `python` random seed
keras.utils.set_random_seed(812)

# This will make TensorFlow ops as deterministic as possible, but it will
# affect the overall performance, so it's not enabled by default.
# `enable_op_determinism()` is introduced in TensorFlow 2.9.
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()


"""
## Weight initialization in Keras

Most of the layers in Keras have `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer`
parameters. These parameters allow you to specify the strategy used for
initializing the weights of layer variables. The following built-in initializers
are available as part of `tf.keras.initializers`:
"""

initializers_list = [
    initializers.RandomNormal,
    initializers.RandomUniform,
    initializers.TruncatedNormal,
    initializers.VarianceScaling,
    initializers.GlorotNormal,
    initializers.GlorotUniform,
    initializers.HeNormal,
    initializers.HeUniform,
    initializers.LecunNormal,
    initializers.LecunUniform,
    initializers.Orthogonal,
]

"""
In a reproducible model, the weights of the model should be initialized with
same values in subsequent runs. First, we'll check how initializers behave when
they are called multiple times with same `seed` value.
"""

for initializer in initializers_list:
    print(f"Running {initializer}")

    for iteration in range(2):
        # In order to get same results across multiple runs from an initializer,
        # you need to specify a seed value. Note that this is not related to
        # keras.utils.set_random_seed or tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism.
        # If you comment those lines, you will still get the same results.
        result = float(initializer(seed=42)(shape=(1, 1)))
        print(f"\tIteration --> {iteration} // Result --> {result}")
    print("\n")


"""
Now, let's inspect how two different initializer objects behave when they are
have the same seed value.
"""

# Setting the seed value for an initializer will cause two different objects
# to produce same results.
glorot_normal_1 = keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=42)
glorot_normal_2 = keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=42)

input_dim, neurons = 3, 5

# Call two different objects with same shape
result_1 = glorot_normal_1(shape=(input_dim, neurons))
result_2 = glorot_normal_2(shape=(input_dim, neurons))

# Check if the results are equal.
equal = tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(result_1, result_2).numpy()
print(f"Are the results equal? {equal}")

"""
If the seed value is not set (or different seed values are used), two different
objects will produce different results. Since the random seed is set at the beginning
of the notebook, the results will be same in the sequential runs. This is related
to the `keras.utils.set_random_seed`.
"""

glorot_normal_3 = keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
glorot_normal_4 = keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()

# Let's call the initializer.
result_3 = glorot_normal_3(shape=(input_dim, neurons))

# Call the second initializer.
result_4 = glorot_normal_4(shape=(input_dim, neurons))

equal = tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(result_3, result_4).numpy()
print(f"Are the results equal? {equal}")

"""
`result_3` and `result_4` will be different, but when you run the notebook
again, `result_3` will have identical values to the ones in the previous run.
Same goes for `result_4`.
"""

"""
## Reproducibility in model training process
If you want to reproduce the results of a model training process, you need to
control the randomness sources during the training process. In order to show a
realistic example, this section utilizes `tf.data` using parallel map and shuffle
operations.

In order to start, let's create a simple function which returns the history
object of the Keras model.
"""


def train_model(train_data: tf.data.Dataset, test_data: tf.data.Dataset) -> dict:
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(32, 32, 1)),
            layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            layers.Dropout(0.2),
            layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
            layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
            layers.Dropout(0.2),
            layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
            layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
            layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dropout(0.2),
            layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

    # model.fit has a `shuffle` parameter which has a default value of `True`.
    # If you are using array-like objects, this will shuffle the data before
    # training. This argument is ignored when `x` is a generator or
    # `tf.data.Dataset`.
    history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=5, validation_data=test_data)

    print(f"Model accuracy on test data: {model.evaluate(test_data)[1] * 100:.2f}%")

    return history.history


# Load the MNIST dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (
    test_images,
    test_labels,
) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Construct tf.data.Dataset objects
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))

"""
Remember we called `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()` at the
beginning of the function. This makes the `tf.data` operations deterministic.
However, making `tf.data` operations deterministic comes with a performance
cost.
If you want to learn more about it, please check this [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism#determinism_and_tfdata).

Small summary what's going on here. Models have `kernel_initializer` and
`bias_initializer` parameters. Since we set random seeds using
`keras.utils.set_random_seed` in the beginning of the notebook, the initializers
will produce same results in the sequential runs. Additionally, TensorFlow
operations have now become deterministic. Frequently, you will be utilizing GPUs
that have thousands of hardware threads which causes non-deterministic behavior
to occur.
"""


def prepare_dataset(image, label):
    # Cast and normalize the image
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0

    # Expand the channel dimension
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)

    # Resize the image
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (32, 32))

    return image, label


"""
`tf.data.Dataset` objects have a `shuffle` method which shuffles the data.
This method has a `buffer_size` parameter which controls the size of the
buffer. If you set this value to `len(train_images)`, the whole dataset will
be shuffled. If the buffer size is equal to the length of the dataset,
then the elements will be shuffled in a completely random order.

Main drawback of setting the buffer size to the length of the dataset is that
filling the buffer can take a while depending on the size of the dataset.

Here is a small summary of what's going on here:
1) The `shuffle()` method creates a buffer of the specified size.
2) The elements of the dataset are randomly shuffled and placed into the buffer.
3) The elements of the buffer are then returned in a random order.

Since `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()` is enabled and we set
random seeds using `keras.utils.set_random_seed` in the beginning of the
notebook, the `shuffle()` method will produce same results in the sequential
runs.
"""
# Prepare the datasets, batch-map --> vectorized operations
train_data = (
    train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(train_images))
    .batch(batch_size=64)
    .map(prepare_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

test_data = (
    test_ds.batch(batch_size=64)
    .map(prepare_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

"""
Train the model for the first time.
"""

history = train_model(train_data, test_data)
```

Error message:

```
Detected at node 'gradient_tape/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/UnsortedSegmentSum' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "t.py", line 247, in <module>
      history = train_model(train_data, test_data)
    File "t.py", line 162, in train_model
      history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=5, validation_data=test_data)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 997, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 577, in minimize
      loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 635, in _compute_gradients
      tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss
    File "C:\Users\LAB\anaconda3\envs\mangoo\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 510, in _get_gradients
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
Node: 'gradient_tape/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/UnsortedSegmentSum'
Deterministic GPU implementation of unsorted segment reduction op not available.
         [[{{node gradient_tape/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/UnsortedSegmentSum}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1645]
```